# Ответ сервера возвращает json, расшифровать не удается

Tags: java, шифрование

Ответ сервера возвращает словарь, приложение расшифровывает и скорее всего когда отправляет данные серверу, тоже шифрует.

"data":"q1YKDSkuyS9KVbLKK83JqQUA","hash":"9ce82a68a7affe3cf8c4a6e6a11f3e52"

в исходниках есть такое:

```
    package p082c.p083a.p084a;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import p086d.p087a.p088a.p089a.C1367a;


public class C1151b {

/* renamed from: a */
private final C1152a f3943a;

/* renamed from: c.a.a.b$a */
public static class C1152a {

    /* renamed from: a */
    private byte[] f3944a;

    /* renamed from: b */
    private int f3945b;

    /* renamed from: c */
    private int f3946c;

    /* renamed from: d */
    private int f3947d;

    /* renamed from: e */
    private String f3948e;

    /* renamed from: f */
    private String f3949f;

    /* renamed from: g */
    private String f3950g;

    /* renamed from: h */
    private String f3951h;

    /* renamed from: i */
    private String f3952i;

    /* renamed from: j */
    private String f3953j;

    /* renamed from: k */
    private String f3954k;

    /* renamed from: l */
    private String f3955l;

    /* renamed from: m */
    private SecureRandom f3956m;

    /* renamed from: n */
    private IvParameterSpec f3957n;

    /* renamed from: a */
    public static C1152a m5791a(String str, String str2, byte[] bArr) {
        C1152a aVar = new C1152a();
        aVar.mo5298a(bArr);
        aVar.mo5304d(str);
        aVar.mo5306f(str2);
        aVar.mo5302c(128);
        aVar.mo5305e("AES");
        aVar.mo5301b("UTF8");
        aVar.mo5300b(1);
        aVar.mo5303c("SHA1");
        aVar.mo5294a(0);
        aVar.mo5295a("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aVar.mo5308h("SHA1PRNG");
        aVar.mo5307g("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        return aVar;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: b */
    public String m5793b() {
        return this.f3950g;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: c */
    public int m5795c() {
        return this.f3946c;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: d */
    public String m5797d() {
        return this.f3952i;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: e */
    public String m5799e() {
        return this.f3954k;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: f */
    public int m5801f() {
        return this.f3947d;
    }

    /* renamed from: g */
    private byte[] m5804g() {
        return this.f3944a;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: h */
    public IvParameterSpec m5806h() {
        return this.f3957n;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: i */
    public String m5807i() {
        return this.f3949f;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: j */
    public String m5809j() {
        return this.f3951h;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: k */
    public int m5811k() {
        return this.f3945b;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: l */
    public String m5814l() {
        return this.f3948e;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: m */
    public String m5815m() {
        return this.f3953j;
    }

    /* access modifiers changed from: private */
    /* renamed from: n */
    public SecureRandom m5816n() {
        return this.f3956m;
    }

    /* renamed from: o */
    private String m5817o() {
        return this.f3955l;
    }

    /* renamed from: a */
    public C1152a mo5294a(int i) {
        this.f3946c = i;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: a */
    public C1152a mo5295a(String str) {
        this.f3950g = str;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: a */
    public C1152a mo5296a(SecureRandom secureRandom) {
        this.f3956m = secureRandom;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: a */
    public C1152a mo5297a(IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec) {
        this.f3957n = ivParameterSpec;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: a */
    public C1152a mo5298a(byte[] bArr) {
        this.f3944a = bArr;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: a */
    public C1151b mo5299a() {
        mo5296a(SecureRandom.getInstance(m5817o()));
        mo5297a(new IvParameterSpec(m5804g()));
        return new C1151b(this, (C1150a) null);
    }

    /* renamed from: b */
    public C1152a mo5300b(int i) {
        this.f3947d = i;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: b */
    public C1152a mo5301b(String str) {
        this.f3952i = str;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: c */
    public C1152a mo5302c(int i) {
        this.f3945b = i;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: c */
    public C1152a mo5303c(String str) {
        this.f3954k = str;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: d */
    public C1152a mo5304d(String str) {
        this.f3949f = str;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: e */
    public C1152a mo5305e(String str) {
        this.f3951h = str;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: f */
    public C1152a mo5306f(String str) {
        this.f3948e = str;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: g */
    public C1152a mo5307g(String str) {
        this.f3953j = str;
        return this;
    }

    /* renamed from: h */
    public C1152a mo5308h(String str) {
        this.f3955l = str;
        return this;
    }
}

private C1151b(C1152a aVar) {
    this.f3943a = aVar;
}

/* synthetic */ C1151b(C1152a aVar, C1150a aVar2) {
    this(aVar);
}

/* renamed from: a */
public static C1151b m5786a(String str, String str2, byte[] bArr) {
    try {
        return C1152a.m5791a(str, str2, bArr).mo5299a();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

/* renamed from: a */
private SecretKey m5787a(char[] cArr) {
    return new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(this.f3943a.m5815m()).generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(cArr, this.f3943a.m5814l().getBytes(this.f3943a.m5797d()), this.f3943a.m5801f(), this.f3943a.m5811k())).getEncoded(), this.f3943a.m5809j());
}

/* renamed from: c */
private char[] m5788c(String str) {
    MessageDigest instance = MessageDigest.getInstance(this.f3943a.m5799e());
    instance.update(str.getBytes(this.f3943a.m5797d()));
    return C1367a.m6999c(instance.digest(), 1).toCharArray();
}

/* renamed from: a */
public String mo5292a(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] a = C1367a.m6994a(str, this.f3943a.m5795c());
    SecretKey a2 = m5787a(m5788c(this.f3943a.m5807i()));
    Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance(this.f3943a.m5793b());
    instance.init(2, a2, this.f3943a.m5806h(), this.f3943a.m5816n());
    return new String(instance.doFinal(a));
}

/* renamed from: b */
public String mo5293b(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    SecretKey a = m5787a(m5788c(this.f3943a.m5807i()));
    byte[] bytes = str.getBytes(this.f3943a.m5797d());
    Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance(this.f3943a.m5793b());
    instance.init(1, a, this.f3943a.m5806h(), this.f3943a.m5816n());
    return C1367a.m6999c(instance.doFinal(bytes), this.f3943a.m5795c());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

"SHA1-это односторонний алгоритм хеширования. Вы не можете получить исходное содержимое обратно.
Если вам нужна двусторонняя схема шифрования, попробуйте использовать AES (или RSA, но это может быть излишним)."

Источник:
[SHA1 decryption of a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14894504/4827341)

Comment: Возможно, я не силен в java, этот отрывок кода я нашел в декомпилированных исходниках приложения, не уверен даже что это относится к расшифровке или к шифровке. В ответе ключ data содержит значение , которое шифруется сервером, приложение его расшифровывает и выводит строки в кириллице(с латиницей). Возможно что и hash передан не случайно, он является либо хэшем data либо хеш-ключом или солью. В криптографии знания тоже поверхностные.

Comment: попробовал вам помочь используя код в ответе из ссылки ниже, но мне не удается. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322002/what-causes-the-error-java-security-invalidkeyexception-parameters-missing